# Swift: Could not find an overload for '|' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift

Trying to incorporate Parse into a new Swift project.

When I get to this block:

```
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten
```

I'm getting this error in XCode 6:

```
Could not find an overload for '|' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

Anyone happen to know what's wrong with that syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `.value` then use the result to create a `PFLogInFields` instance:

```
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields(PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword.value 
    | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton.value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Timothy's answer is right but it is better to correct the code with Swift's update.

```
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields(rawValue: 
PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword.rawValue | 
PFLogInFieldsLogInButton.rawValue)
```

**Second way:**

You can use operator overloading for shorter code:

```
func +=(inout slf: PFLogInFields,other: PFLogInFields)-> PFLogInFields{
    slf = PFLogInFields(rawValue: slf.rawValue | other.rawValue)!
}

func +(a: PFLogInFields, b: PFLogInFields)-> PFLogInFields{
    return PFLogInFields(rawValue: a.rawValue | b.rawValue)!
}
```

And further:

```
logInViewController.fields = .UsernameAndPassword + .LogInButton
```

or

```
logInViewController.fields = .UsernameAndPassword
logInViewController.fields += .LogInButton
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2 it seems that the accepted solution or other answers don't work.
I solved my problem by enclosing the PFLogInFields in an array. Everything seems to work just fine.

So instead of:

```
    loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.Facebook | PFLogInFields.Twitter
```

I wrote:

```
   loginViewController.fields = [PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword, PFLogInFields.LogInButton, PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten, PFLogInFields.SignUpButton, PFLogInFields.Facebook, PFLogInFields.Twitter]
```

Comment: You should also be able to avoid the `PFLogInFields` prefix in the case where you set the value like as an Array

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a moving target, as none of the answers here seem to work anymore.  At present I have to use this:

```
logInViewController.fields =  PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton
```