# Setting bitmask enum declared in objective-c from swift

Tags: objective-c, enums, swift, parse-platform, bit-masks

I'm trying to use Parse SDK for iOS in my new project. It has viewController with enum property;

```
typedef enum {
    PFLogInFieldsNone = 0,
    PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword = 1 << 0,
    PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten = 1 << 1,
    PFLogInFieldsLogInButton = 1 << 2,
    PFLogInFieldsFacebook = 1 << 3,
    PFLogInFieldsTwitter = 1 << 4,
    PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton = 1 << 5,
    PFLogInFieldsDismissButton = 1 << 6,

    PFLogInFieldsDefault = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton |      PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton
 } PFLogInFields;
```

According to tutorial in Objective-C I should set it in this way:

```
 [logInViewController setFields: PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];
```

I'm trying to do it in this way(using swift):

```
loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton
```

But I get error:"'PFLogInFields' is not convertible to 'Bool'"

So, what is the correct way to set such kind of properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132244/swift-could-not-find-an-overload-for-that-accepts-the-supplied-arguments) for how to set `PFLogInFields` in Swift. It worked for me!!

Comment: I've just add one more option that contains all I need PFLogInFieldsFull =PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton | PFLogInFieldsFacebook  to make it work. But the the answer you provided is definitely much better. Thanks.

Comment: @Vitaliy1 Awesome. Hooray for 3AM programming!

Answer (score 2):

Consecutive enums in Objective-C should be refactored to use `NS_ENUM`, and bit-field enums should be refactored to use `NS_OPTIONS`.

You should change

```
typedef enum {
    //...
} PFLogInFields;
```

to

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, PFLogInFields) {
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you have to prefix the enums with the Type. I am not sure if this works automatically with Objective-C imports, but it might:

```
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.PFLogInFieldsTwitter | ...
```

If the library were ported to Swift standard, the fields would already expect `PFLoginFields` and the enum items would be defined in a manner so that you can write

```
logInViewController.fields = .Twitter | .Facebook ...
```